# Probability: $12$ questions $12$ answers to be matched

Tags: probability

There are $12$ questions and $12$ answers on a test. Assuming each answer can only be matched to $1$ question, what is the probability of getting $4$ correct matching randomly and how would you calculate this?

Comment: Is it EXACTLY four or at least four? I would first consider all the possible options ($12!$) and see how many cases there are that fulfill the requirement.

Comment: Hint:  you'll want to use [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Select $4$ questions to be matched with $4$ corresponding answers, in $^{12}C_4$  ways.
 And ensure that rest $8$ questions are matched with any, but not their correct answers.
This is done using De-arrangement of $8$, i.e. $D_8$.

Total possible arrangements are obviously $12!$.